# Data isn't render on first load until button is click in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the data just fine. However, when I'm trying to implemented a filter system, I'm not getting all the data on the initial load until I click "all" filter button. The filter works fine, just wanted to have all the data display on the initial load before there's any filtering.

Just expect to see all data on initial load.

```
function AllMovies(){

  const [isloading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loadedMovies, setLoadedMovies] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(loadedMovies);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    fetch('https://movies.json'
    ).then(response =>{
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
      const movies = [];

      for (const key in data){
        const movie = {
          id: key,
          ...data[key]
        };

        movies.push(movie)
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
      setLoadedMovies(movies);
    });

  }, []);


  function eventCategoryClick(e){
    const nameSelecion = e.currentTarget.textContent;
    const filtered =  loadedMovies.filter((item) => item.category === nameSelecion);
      setCategory(filtered);
  }

  if(isloading){
    return (
      <div><Spinner animation="border" variant="danger" /></div>
      );
  }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>New Release</h1>
            <CoverMovieList movies={loadedMovies} />
            <h2>All Movies</h2>
            <div className="filterContainer">
              <Button className="filterBtn" variant="outline-warning" onClick={eventCategoryClick}>All</Button>
              <Button className="filterBtn" variant="outline-warning" onClick={eventCategoryClick}>Action</Button>
              <Button  className="filterBtn" variant="outline-warning" onClick={eventCategoryClick}>Family</Button>
              <Button className="filterBtn" variant="outline-warning" onClick={eventCategoryClick}>Fantasy</Button>
              <Button className="filterBtn" variant="outline-warning" onClick={eventCategoryClick}>Horror</Button>
            </div>
          <MoviesList movies={category} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default AllMovies;
```

Comment: did you forget to setCategory after movies first loaded?

Comment: What specifically "isn't rendering"?  You have two custom components, `<CoverMovieList>` and `<MoviesList>`.  Are you specifically referring to one of those?  Which one?  What does it internally do with the data provided to it?

Comment: @wctiger thank you! Yes, I totally forgot to do that. Works now!

Answer (score 0):

You need just add `setCategory(movies)` inside useEffect.
Your category state is an empty array therefore while loading the first time it does not show anything.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState(loadedMovies);
```

loadedMovies is an empty array.